# How to get value from response body by using environment variable

Tags: api, postman

This is my response body, I want to get the value of status by using an environment variable.

```
{
   "success":[
      {
         "code":"200",
         "message":"Success",
         "details":"Station was retrieved successfully."
      }
   ]
}
```

i can get value of status code as: jsonData.success.code,

But instead of this, I'm doing it like,
I m setting an environment variable named 'sh' n I gave value as "code"...

```
pm.environment.set("sh","code");

var s = pm.environment.get("sh")

jsonData.status.success[0].s
```

By doing like this I'm not able to get the path...Any solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what your actual response body is but this should probably work:

```
let statusCode = pm.response.json().success[0].code

pm.environment.set("statusCode", statusCode)
```

Ensure that you create an environment file before running the request.